# how to remove duplicate Docker image & container using Jenkinsfile

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dynamic-variables

I want to remove **duplicate** docker Container if it's already exits then delete neither ignore and continue execute Jenkinsfile so how can i develop this Jenkinsfile ?
please help me !

Comment: There can be no duplicate images nor containers. Please describe in detail what you consider a duplicate.

Comment: Just clean your non-used docker container and image on schedule. Or add `docker container prune` or `docker image prune` on your Jenkins file to clean non used image and container

Comment: for ex,

I start Jenkinsfile and output like to be its make Dockerfile then after Its make 1 Docker Image [ Name as 1] then my Jenkins build container  [ Name as 2 based on { Docker image 1} ]  so if Docker Container 2 is already exist in my local machine or server so delete neither ignore and execute Jenkins.

as per your replay if i execute so its delete my all container which is in not running. But i want to delete only based on name which i mention in [ Ex. Name as 2 its make based on Image 1]

hope you understand my query.